# php mongodb how to add php array without it creating a subarray of element 0

Tags: php, mongodb

Going to try this again as I think my previous post [Inserting complex PHP array directly into mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942017/inserting-complex-php-array-directly-into-mongodb) was poorly asked, or didn't provide a tl;dr...  I'm having a really hard time finding much documentation on anything past the basics.

My array looks like:

```
    [publication] => Array
    (
        [_id] => 100000009
        [title] => title
        [author] => author
    )
```

I'm using PHPdriver for mongodb and I directly add the array like this:

```
    $result = $publications->insertOne([
        $publication
    ]);
```

and while this works, it give me this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a910438834a9c2314006cf6"),
    "0" : {
            "_id" : "100000009",
            "title" : "uf",
            "author" : "author"
    }
}
```

How do I make it like this instead:

```
{
    "_id" : "100000009",
    "title" : "uf",
    "author" : "author"        
}
```

Without manually breaking each line out into a "id" => $publication['id'] inside the insertOne statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to insert a document, not a mongodb array.

You are creating a new array wrapping your document.

Try this:

```
$result = $publications->insertOne($publication);
```

Comment: Not sure whether to laugh or cry.... You are of course correct.. I can't believe I did that. Thanks